# SQL query to show result equals 0 where clause is not met

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query. Player 'Judd' does not have an entry where PlaceFinished = 4.

```
select PlaceFinished, count(PlaceFinished) as PlaceCount , sum (PointsAwarded) as Points 
from Teams_tbl T
where Player = 'Judd' and PlaceFinished is not NULL and PlaceFinished in (1,2,3,4) 
group by PlaceFinished
```

The current result is

```
PlaceFinished   PlaceCount
1               6
2               2
3               6
```

I would like it to show:

```
PlaceFinished   PlaceCount
1               6
2               2
3               6
4               0
```

I tried to create a virtual table with a Left Outer Join but the result is the same

```
Declare @Places Table(
place int
)

Insert into @Places
select distinct PlaceFinished from Teams_tbl

select p.place, count(PlaceFinished) as PlaceCount , sum (PointsAwarded) as Points from Teams_tbl T
Left Outer Join @Places P
on T.PlaceFinished = p.place
where Player = 'Judd' and PlaceFinished is not NULL group by p.place
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that all PlaceFinished values exist in the table, regardless of player, you can do conditional aggregation:

```
select PlaceFinished,
       count(case when Player = 'Judd' then 1 end) as PlaceCount,
       sum(case when Player = 'Judd' then PointsAwarded else 0 end) as Points 
from Teams_tbl T
where PlaceFinished in (1,2,3,4) 
group by PlaceFinished
```

Answer (score 0):

Right join because you are looking for a place (fourth) that doesn't have a row in placefinished as Judd has never placed fourth. PlaceFinished is not null filters out all places that the player has never come in, so get rid of it. Also, filter for Judd using a derived table, so that join stays outer. Everything else is good :-)

```
select p.place, 
       count(PlaceFinished) as PlaceCount , 
       sum (PointsAwarded) as Points
from 
(Select placefinished as ..., FROM Teams_tbl Where Player='Judd') T
 Right Outer Join 
 @Places P
 on T.PlaceFinished = p.place 
 group by p.place
```